# How to set url route to a different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

What kind of route path can I use to link to a subdomain page from a non-subdomain page?

I have added subdomains to my site by following [Railscast#123](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised).

The key changes I've made to my site are matching each blogger to a unique subdomain.

**routes.rb**

```
match '', to: 'blogs#show', constraints: {subdomain: /.+/}
```

**blogs_controller.rb**

```
def show
@blog = Blog.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
end
```

**blogs/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to blog.name, root_url(subdomain: blog.subdomain) %>
```

As a result, the blogging application `http://www.blog.com` has subdomains for each type of blogger, such as for pirates `http://www.pirate.blog.com` and ninjas `http://www.ninja.blog.com`.

I currently have an `_article.html.erb` partial that I render in both my homepage (with no subdomain) and in my blog pages (with subdomain). What route can I use that will link the main home page (with no subdomain) to a specific article nested in a blogger's subdomain such as `http://www.ninja.blog.com/articles/ninja-stars`?

Currently, linking to a ninja stars article through a `article` path in the partial will route me to:

```
http://www.ninja.blog.com/articles/ninja-stars
```

from a ninja subdomain page (which is what I want), but to

```
http://www.blog.com/articles/ninja-stars
```

from the main page with no subdomain (not what I want).

Is there a way to force the path to a specific subdomain through something like, `article(subdomain: article.blog.subdomain)`? I want every article link to go to a subdomained page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make all links to articles have the subdomain of the author blog, I used

`article_url(article, subdomain: article.blog.subdomain)`

as my path.